# What method families exist in objective-c/cocoa for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I am a experienced developer that is new to iOS developement (on iPhone in particular). A project I am working on is using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC).

I was doing some research on ARC and came across this document: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html and in a section titled: "Retained return values" it states that an attribute can be used to indicate that the caller expects to take ownership of a +1 retain count. It also goes on to state that ARC will automatically add the attribute to methods if it detects it is in particular method families (it specifically names: alloc, copy, init, mutableCopy, and new)

From further reading it seems that method families are simply method naming conventions. My understanding is that if the method name starts with a method family then it is in that method family. So for example

```
+(id) init
+(id) initWithName:(NSString*)name
```

are both part of the init method family.

**My question is:** Is there a formal list of defined Method Families for iOS development and if so, what are they / where might I find it?

below is the section llvm.org I mentioned above:

> Section 3.2.2: Retained return values states:
>
> A function or method which returns a retainable object pointer type
>   may be marked as returning a retained value, signifying that the
>   caller expects to take ownership of a +1 retain count. This is done by
>   adding the ns_returns_retained attribute to the function or method
>   declaration, like so:
>
> id foo(void) __attribute((ns_returns_retained));
>   - (id) foo __attribute((ns_returns_retained)); This attribute is part of the type of the function or method.
>
> When returning from such a function or method, ARC retains the value
>   at the point of evaluation of the return statement, before leaving all
>   local scopes.
>
> When receiving a return result from such a function or method, ARC
>   releases the value at the end of the full-expression it is contained
>   within, subject to the usual optimizations for local values.
>
> Rationale: this formalizes direct transfers of ownership from a callee
>   to a caller. The most common scenario this models is the retained
>   return from init, alloc, new, and copy methods, but there are other
>   cases in the frameworks. After optimization there are typically no
>   extra retains and releases required.
>
> Methods in the alloc, copy, init, mutableCopy, and new families are
>   implicitly marked **attribute**((ns_returns_retained)). This may be
>   suppressed by explicitly marking the method
>   **attribute**((ns_returns_not_retained)).
>
> It is undefined behavior if the method to which an Objective-C message
>   send statically resolves has different retain semantics on its result
>   from the method it dynamically resolves to. It is undefined behavior
>   if a block or function call is made through a static type with
>   different retain semantics on its result from the implementation of
>   the called block or function.
>
> Rationale: Mismatches with returned results will cause over-retains or
>   over-releases, depending on the direction. Again, the rule about
>   function calls is really just an application of the existing C/C++
>   rule about calling functions through an incompatible function type.

Comment: i would note that these naming convention families are not iOS particular but Objective-C ARC particular (of which iOS and OS X are the only notable users currently (that i am aware of))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know that I've seen a formal list of method families, but your analysis is basically correct. I believe the only method naming conventions that have compiler-enforced semantics are those mentioned in your post, namely alloc, init, copy (and mutableCopy), and new. Even before/without ARC, the clang static analyzer included in Xcode uses those naming conventions to find memory management problems, and they're also the basis of the longstanding memory management rules for Objective-C programmers prior to ARC.

Namely, if you create an object using a method that begins with init, copy, mutableCopy or new, you "own" that object and are responsible for releasing it later. Objects created or returned by methods with any other name, are *not* owned by you, the caller, and if you want to keep a reference to them, you must retain them. Every retain you make must be balanced by a later release, when you're done with the object reference. Finally, calling autorelease on an object puts it in the innermost autorelease pool. The pool is responsible for releasing the object later, where later is sometime after the current scope. So, release and autorelease are both valid ways of relinquishing your retain on an object.

Now, the rules I've set forth shouldn't (and can't) be followed by you, the programmer, under ARC. However, ARC is essentially a system whereby the compiler with help from the static analyzer knows these rules and inserts the necessary memory management calls for you at compile time. So, if you're looking to develop an understanding of what ARC is doing behind-the-scenes, understanding these rules is a good start.

This turned out a bit longwinded, but the point is that the methods you've named are the only ones I know of that have this enforced naming convention in Objective-C, and it stems from the memory management rules set forth above. There are other naming conventions in Objective-C, to be sure, but they're standard style conventions, not something that's enforced anywhere.

Answer (score 9):

[Section 5 of the same document](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#family) is titled "Method Families". It lists all the currently defined families, which are the ones you identified above; `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, `mutableCopy`, and `init`. It also lists the criteria for being part of that family. Mostly, it's just based on the method name, but it also depends on the return type. For example, a member of the `copy` family must return an object; a copy method that has a `void` return type will not be considered part of the `copy` method family.

Comment: Yes, that section is where I came up with the above list from. I realize naming conventions are important to objective-c/cocoa, but I am somewhat surprised the compiler is influenced by naming conventions. I guess one of the things that worry me is what other compiler optimizations I may be getting because of the way I named my function. I wasn't sure if the list presented in the ARC documentation was a full list for the language, or just the one's that come into play for ARC.

Comment: I was not aware that the return type was part of the qualification's for family membership, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Look at official Apple Developer documentation about [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH). Seems, your list is complete: “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (only 4 keywords).

Answer (score 0):

I would include the convenience constructors provided by some Cocoa classes:

```
 - +stringWith*                        // Various ways to make NSString objects
 - +arrayWith*, +dictionaryWith*, etc. // Make collections
 - +dateWith*                          // Make NSDate objects
 - etc.                                // Many, many others
```

They all return a new, autoreleased instance of the class they are sent to - except for some special cases, see for instance @Peter Hosey's comment.

I don't know if there are any formal rules, but the pattern is that the constructor name is composed of the class name without the `NS` part (and without the `Mutable` part, too, for mutable classes) followed by `With<Parameter Type>:` and one or more parameters. The name begins with a lower case letter (except the usual suspects, like `URLWithString:`.)

For instance, the following line provides an autoreleased `NSArray` instance with a single element:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObject: @"Test"]
```

I don't know if there are any special rules in the compiler to recognize this type of constructor.

Comment: They don't necessarily return an autoreleased instance. They can return an existing instance, especially a singleton or interned object (NSNumber, for example, interns objects for certain integer values, at least on 32-bit).

Comment: Right, forgot about that. Added a comment, thank you. Another example that comes to mind is `stringWithString:` which just returns the same instance if passed an immutable string.